# wrap each line into span tags (IE7)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got a script right now that works all browsers GTE IE8

And i need it to work in IE7 aswell can somebody tell me what i did wrong in this script

[image: Chrome up, IE7 down]

In this picture you see How it works in all other browsers and you see the dark area in IE7 is the bugged area cause the background is on the div and not on the line

[image: IE7 up, Chrome down]

Kode from IE7 and Chrome

last but not least my script to make this happen:

```
function padSubsequentLines(element) {
            var words = element.innerHTML.split(' ');
            element.innerHTML = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                element.innerHTML += '<span>' + words[i] + '</span> ';
            }
            var spans = element.childNodes;
            var currentOffset = spans[0].offsetTop;
            var html = '<span class="line">';
            for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
                if (spans[i].nodeType === 3)
                    continue;
                if (spans[i].offsetTop > currentOffset) {
                    html += '</span><span class="line">';
                    currentOffset = spans[i].offsetTop;
                }
                html += spans[i].innerHTML + ' ';
            }
            html += '</span>';
            element.innerHTML = html;
    }
```

Body tag htmlscript

```
<body onload="padSubsequentLines(document.getElementById('question_heading'));">
```

Comment: i know its an old question - asked and answered but since i arrived here from google while search a solution i decided to comment it.

i needed to do exactly what you needed mate and need to from time to time to wrap words in seperate line with a html opening and closing tag so i created a tool  -  there it is http://goo.gl/IFsVA (hope this helps anyone :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear from the question exactly what you are trying to achieve. By reading through the code it seems you are wrapping each word in a span, and then using that span's location to work out whether or not it is on a new line, this then leads to each word on the same line being merged together inside a new span, each with class="line".

Whilst reading the offset position of a newly formed span — formed in the same block of code — could be causing your IE7 issue, because it's location information may not be recalculated yet... It really does beg the question as to why you are doing this? Especially if you take the name of your function `padSubsequentLines` into account.

If all you are doing is padding between lines of words you should use `line-height:` in your style/css.

#### update

I'd recommend — assuming you don't have direct access to the markup, which would have to be very likely — that you just stick with your first part of the code. This would be the part that wraps each word with a span. On these spans I'd then apply the class that applies the background colour you want, there should be no need to combine them into their constituent lines. This will remove the need to calculate `offsetTop`, and should even work for IE7. As I stated before, if you require padding between lines, use `line-height`.

```
function padSubsequentLines(element) {
  var 
    words = element.innerHTML.split(' '),
    count = words.length,
    html = '',
    i
  ;
  for (i=0; i<count; i++) {
    html += '<span class="background">' + words[i] + ' </span>';
  }
  element.innerHTML = html;
}
```

***Note**: You will need to make sure the spaces between words are kept within the spans, so that the background colour appears seemless.*

After the above, if you still have problems with regard to the background colour stretching to fill the space in IE7, I'd look to your CSS definition for your span elements and make sure they aren't being `overflow:hidden`, `zoom:1` or `display:block`.

Comment: I need to let the background be behind the words and not the on the div, so i need to get each line into a span tag so i have 2 separate spans else it will do the background on the hole area

Comment: @SimonPertersen I'm guessing you don't have access to the html? Is the markup being generated by some kind of js plugin or similar...

Comment: @SimonPertersen I've updated my recommendation based on your comment.

Comment: it solved the problem in IE, just a note(this makes very small spaces in Ipad) but thx you solved the problem that i needed to fix